# My product not display in frontend

Tags: magento-1.7

I have installed Magento 1.7.0.0 on my local server and added new categories and products in  my Magentoshop. But it is not shown on the homepage (frontend-myshop).. .

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following things:

- Make sure the products are set to active/visible
- Make sure all categories and products are inside one 'root' category
- Look in the right category page.
- If the products aren't showing in the parent category, make sure the parent category is set to Anchor (in admin, go to `Catalog > Categories` and in the right category, there is an option 'Is anchor', set this to 'yes'.

For example, if you have a category 'Electronics' with sub-categories 'Computers' and 'Tablets', Electronics needs to be set to anchor if you want products from Computers and Tablets to show there.

---

There is one additional effect to 'anchor' categories, which you may not want. Setting a category to 'anchor' activates something Magento calls 'layered navigation', which is basically some extra sorting and filtering options. I don't know how to disable this, but if you don't want this feature to show, the easiest solution is to hide the block/div with CSS.